# No compiler warning for 'const' pointers of non POD types when overriding a method

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

An example where one is overriding POD return type without `const` in the derived class:

```
struct B1
{
    virtual const int* f();
};

struct D1 : B1
{
    int* f() override;
};
```

Compilers like Clang and GCC raise a warning:

> invalid covariant return type for 'virtual int* D1::f()'

When same scenario is applied but return type is some struct/class, no warning is raised:

```
struct S
{
};

struct B2
{
    virtual const S* f();
};

struct D2 : B2
{
    S* f() override;
};
```

I compiled this on different versions of GCC.
I would have expected similar warning when struct/class pointer is returned in the derived class when not using `const` declaration.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour you observe is consistent with the Standard. From [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)<sup>#</sup>:

> ##### 13.3 Virtual functions       [class.virtual]
>
> …
> <sup>8</sup>     The
> return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the
> return type of the overridden function or *covariant* with the classes
> of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`,
> the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the
> following criteria:
> <sup>(8.1)</sup>   — both are
> pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both
> are rvalue references to classes
> <sup>(8.2)</sup>   — the
> class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in
> the return type of `D::f`, or is an unambiguous and accessible direct
> or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
> <sup>(8.3)</sup>   — both pointers or references have the same
> cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f` has
> the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class
> type in the return type of `B::f`.

So, in your second case, all three of the above criteria are met. Note that 8.3 is true because the *pointers* returned are not cv-qualified – the `const` refers to the pointed-to object, not the pointer itself. If you instead declare the base class function as `virtual S* const f();` then the derived class version you have will no longer be valid. Further, the return type in your derived class function is **less** cv-qualified than in the base class; swapping the definitions so that the base class is `virtual S* f();` and the derived is `const S* f() override;` will also make it invalid.

However, in your first snippet, the returned type of the function does *not* meet the 8.1 criterion (`int` is not a class); thus, in order to be a valid override, its return type must be *identical* to that of the base class version.

---

<sup>#</sup> The text hasn't changed significantly in the [latest, online draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#8).

Comment: Interestingly, removing `override` still leaves OP's code with a hard error, instead of silently not overriding the function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat depends. Some compilers whine about incorrect ambigous overloading in that case (function overloads can't differ by return type alone). Once upon a time I believed that this cryptic message alone was the reason for `override` keyword as an extension.